# How to show the name of a file in vba excel form

Tags: excel, forms, vba, upload, label

so i have this form and i have 2 buttons that allow me to upload 2 different files and what i want is to show the file names after they are uploaded under the buttons.

Im thinking of using a label for each button but im stuck, so can you give me ant advice on how to deal with this issue.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code of how you are uploading the files?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'Generate schedule

    If ComboBox3 = "1-1" Then

        Call Main(3)

      ElseIf ComboBox3 = "1-2" Then

        Call Main(4)

      ElseIf ComboBox3 = "2-1" Then

        Call Main(5)

      ElseIf ComboBox3 = "2-2" Then

        Call Main(6)

      ElseIf ComboBox3 = "3-1" Then

        Call Main(7)

      ElseIf ComboBox3 = "3-2" Then

        Call Main(8)

      ElseIf ComboBox3 = "4-1" Then

        Call Main(9)

      ElseIf ComboBox3 = "4-2" Then

        Call Main(10)

      End If

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
'Program map
Dim userBook, userWorkbook, targetWorkbook As Workbook
Dim filter, caption, userFilename As String
Dim targetSheet, sourceSheet, sourceSheetPM As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Worksheets("Program Map").Range("A1:AZ9999").ClearContents

' Making sure that the info will come to this workbook
Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

' getting the program map file
filter = "All Excel files (*.xl??),*.xl??"
caption = "Please Select your Program Map file"
userFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

Set userWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(userFilename)


' copy data from file to target workbook
Dim shtno As Integer
shtno = TextBox1.Value
Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets("Program Map")
Set sourceSheet = userWorkbook.Worksheets(shtno)

targetSheet.Range("A1", "AZ9999").Value = sourceSheet.Range("A1", "AZ9999").Value

' Close original file
userWorkbook.Close


End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
'Banner summary
Dim userBook, userWorkbook, targetWorkbook As Workbook
Dim filter, caption, userFilename As String
Dim targetSheet, sourceSheet, sourceSheetPM As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Worksheets("Banner Summary").Range("A1:AZ9999").ClearContents

' Making sure that the info will come to this workbook
Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

' getting the banner summary file
filter = "All Excel files (*.xl??),*.xl??"
caption = "Please Select your Banner Summary file "
userFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

Set userWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(userFilename)


' copy data from file to target workbook

Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets("Banner Summary")
Set sourceSheet = userWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

targetSheet.Range("A1", "AZ9999").Value = sourceSheet.Range("A1", "AZ9999").Value

' Close original file
userWorkbook.Close

Worksheets("Banner Summary").Range("A1:AA9999").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18), Header:=xlYes

End Sub
Private Sub Label5_Click()



End Sub
Private Sub Label6_Click()



End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim shtno As Integer
shtno = TextBox1.Value

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Me.ComboBox3.AddItem "1-1"
Me.ComboBox3.AddItem "1-2"
Me.ComboBox3.AddItem "2-1"
Me.ComboBox3.AddItem "2-2"
Me.ComboBox3.AddItem "3-1"
Me.ComboBox3.AddItem "3-2"
Me.ComboBox3.AddItem "4-1"
Me.ComboBox3.AddItem "4-2"


End Sub
```